# Maximum number of edges in a graph

Tags: graph-theory

> Let $G$ be a connected graph on 43 vertices. If $G$ does not contain
>   an induced subgraph $K_{5}$, determine the maximum number of edges $G$
>   can have, and explain what $G$ looks like. You do not have to prove
>   your choice of $G$ has maximum size.

I'm really not so sure how to approach this problem. It's a practice problem for an exam I'm preparing for. I tried it for smaller cases. For $n = 5$, we can have $9$ edges (just take $K_{5}$ and remove one edge). I think that we want to repeat this structure for $43$, so any $5$ vertices from our set of $43$ should have $9$ vertices?

I'm really not so sure. I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Clearly, we should have every vertex with degree at least $4$, and at least $4$ vertices with degree $5$ or higher.

Comment: How did you get this answer?

Comment: No vertex with degree $4$ or less can be part of an induced $K_5$ subgraph. $4$ vertices can't form $K_5$.

Answer (score 1):

you can find that number using Turán's theorem. here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n%27s_theorem